# Is there any way to access the files in android which are seen only in rooted phones

Tags: android

I want to develop an android app in which I need to access some files from device and send it to server, but some files cannot be accessed directly, but can be seen only in rooted mobile phones.
So Is there any way by which I can access those files in my app without rooting the device and will I be able to send those files to server without any permission or problem!?

any help would be appriciated, thank you.

Comment: if you need root to see them why would you think you wouldn't need root to get them?

Answer (score 0):

Use ES file explorer application and from side drawer click on show hidden folders. So you can access files.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop

Comment: I don't need an app, instead I need some method by which I can develop my own app to access those files. just like this es explorer as you said I want my app to do that..so Is there any tutorial where I can learn this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you give root persmissions to your application which means you should programmaticaly root the device inside your application!

Comment: ok.. so these ES explorer and all do the same to access those files?

Comment: Yes absolutely, they just can't do it without root access!